# glxinfo does not see environmental variables?

Tags: environment-variables, 64bit, opengl, 32bit

I am running following 32 bit command on 64 bit system:

```
LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo32 -v -t | head -5
```

It's output says

```
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
```

So it looks like 32 bit application is not seeing environmental variables. How can I export variables to 32 bit app?

Comment: I would be surprised if it didn't get the environment variable, I would be less surprised if your version of glxinfo32 simply wasn't compiled with support for that feature, and that message is misleading.

Comment: Why does this have close votes? It's a legitimate question. OP might be wrong about the cause, but the issue itself still remains.

Comment: @ChrisDown I have used this turotrial https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=34104 to compile and install 32 bit glxinfo. I have tried version that comes from Gentoo portage and I have also downloaded newest source code from Mesa page. By analyzing code I have found out that it is not glxinfo which produces additional information in response to environmental variable. It is libgl which checks for this variable and produces verbose output which is what variable name indicates anyway. So this is problem of libgl compilation which comes with Fedora package.